# Is there a C++ format plugin just like Visual Studio

Tags: vimscript, plugin-vim-autoformat

Coding C++ in Visual Studio, if you type `;`, this line will be formatted. For example, typing a `;` after `int i= 1+ 2` will make this line as `int i = 1 + 2;`, which means that each operator is surrounded by two spaces.

So I'm asking if there is such a vim plugin to do so? I've tried `astyle`, it does format my c++ code but it can't add spaces around operator.

Comment: Are you sure that `astyle` cannot add spaces around operators: http://astyle.sourceforge.net/astyle.html#_pad-oper ?

Comment: @Hotschke  oh... Yes, it works

Comment: Have you tried clang-format and its associated vim plugin(s) ?